# Replace Static Table Data w/ External Source and Update Pivot Automatically (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, powerpivot, microsoft-powerbi

1. st tab is a table with data manually pasted from a file
2. nd tab is a pivot based on the 1st tab

Is it possible to replace the 1. st tab with an external data source (load-in the file without pasting it), which has exactly the same headings as the table in the 1. st tab, and so update the 2. nd tab's pivot dynamically with the new content?

Thanks.

Comment: The idea is to be able to load different files and let Pivot update automatically (without needing to recreate it).

Comment: what external database you are suppose to use to update St Tab,, ACCESS,  Oracle or SQL or Excel, please [Edit] your post and be specific,, and yes auto updation is always possible!!

Comment: I just want to load in a text/csv file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load in a CSV file, you can do this from the ribbon:

Data -> From Text/CSV

You then have the option to load to a table in the workbook or just to load a connection.

You can then point the Pivot Table at the newly-loaded data: Analyse -> Change data source.

Comment: This does not answer my question/does not work as the Pivot Table for some reason ties to the source in the 1. st tab

Comment: What happens when you change the source of the pivot table?

Comment: It destroys the old data model

Comment: Try this: Get the 'name' of the table where the csv has been imported to. You'll see this by clicking anywhere on it, then selecting "Design" or "Table Design"  (depending on version) from the ribbon. The name should be on the left hand side of the ribbon. Now go back to your pivot table, and instead of clicking on "Change data source", click the down-arrow on the button and select "Connection Properties". Go to the "Definition" in the pop-up. In the box labelled "Command Text", change this to the table name of the CSV. That should point the pivot table and the data model at the csv.